# Allowing user to override CSS with browser settings for accessibility

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility

I'm a Web Development and Programming student, and through my course, I've found that I'm particularly interested in using Responsive Web Design for "Inclusive and Accessibility" oriented Web Development.

I'm trying to make my website using HTML5 (trying to be as strict as possible, a-la XHTML, and trying to be as valid as possible), I’ve come across a problem in allowing my CSS (colours, fonts, etc...) to more or less take backseat to whatever the user needs in order to use the website.

One thing that I had picked up from Heydon Pickering’s book “Inclusive Design Patterns” is the use of:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" media="none" onload="if(media!='all')media='all'"/>
```

It sounds great, but it fails to validate (using validator.w3.org) because:

```
Error: Bad value none for attribute media on element link: Media query ended prematurely.
```

I understand that I could just use Javascript (jQuery, or such), but in keeping with Progressive Enhancement, I need to make it usable regardless of whether or not Javascript is enabled or not (It’s not my place to force those things on the user).

My main question is, Is there a way I achieve allowing my CSS to be overridden client-side so the user can use settings, that allow them to make the most of their web browsing experience, without the use of Javascript, or just straight up not have valid HTML?

I'm still not that fantastic at overall web-design or programming yet, but It's something I really want to continue doing. and I would be gracious for any and all help relating to this.

Thank you so much.

Comment: `onload="if(media!='all')media='all'"` is already JavaScript

Comment: It's 2017. If you don't have JS enabled you aren't capable of using the web.

Comment: @zero298 Fair enough, so I guess I should have framed it as "How can I do `onload="if(media!='all')media='all'"` without Javascript?"

Comment: That example looks awful, and I can't believe it's from a real book. Comments like Jordan S's, and examples like this one run completely counter to being "inclusive". If nothing else, that example looks like it's meant to be hidden from users with JS disabled, and not meant for all users.

Comment: (If you wanted it to be valid, though, it should be media="not all", not media="none". Again, I find it hard to believe that this is from a book.)

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for your input! I'm still learning the ropes with WebDev in general, let alone accessibility, so I appreciate you letting me know what bad code looks like, it's the kind of guidance I could use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way I achieve allowing my CSS to be overridden client-side so the user can use settings, that allow them to make the most of their web browsing experience, without the use of Javascript, or just straight up not have valid HTML?

Many browsers including Chrome and Firefox have a feature called user stylesheets that allows users to implement custom CSS for a variety of use cases, including accessibility enhancements (e.g. making text larger, or increasing contrast). This functionality is already built-in and does not require any third-party extensions, but extensions like Stylish exist that help manage user stylesheets.

As it is entirely client-side, and already built-in, you do not need to do anything as an author to enable this on your site.

Comment: That's awesome! That will make everything so much easier. I'll have to look into those features more.

Comment: Note that Chrome discontinued support for User Stylesheets in 2014 (see discussion at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=347016#c3 ).  There are, of course, Chrome extensions to accomplish user stylesheets.

Answer (score 1):

> One thing that I had picked up from Heydon Pickering’s book “Inclusive Design Patterns” is the use of:

> ```
>  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" media="none"
> ```

```
        onload="if(media!='all')media='all'"/>
```

The intent of this line is not linked to accessibility but to load the CSS after the page has loaded, not blocking the display of the page in order to preserve what we call the "above the fold" loading. It's more of a "performance" subject.

With `media=none` attribute, the browser will load the stylesheet, and once it has been loaded, it will change the `media` attribute.

This will change nothing for user using screenreaders as they use javascript and CSS too.

> My main question is, Is there a way I achieve allowing my CSS to be overridden client-side so the user can use settings, that allow them to make the most of their web browsing experience, without the use of Javascript, or just straight up not have valid HTML?

This is a totally different question.

If you want your CSS to be overridden from the client-side, the main thing to do is to define the main properties of your CSS within the `body` class and make the rest inherited from the `body` definition using relative units.

```
body {
   font-size: 10px;
}

h1 {
   font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

This way a user who would want to override the size of your website, will only have to override the `body` definition.

Answer (score 0):

CSS stylesheets are also capable of querying what kind of media or device they are being displayed in.  Consider writing a query that leverages different [Media features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#Media_features) for conditional display.

Additionally, one of the most important facets of an accessible web page is proper, well-formatted, standards compliant HTML markup.  That means correct usage of semantic elements such as `<h1>`, `<aside>`, `<header>`, `<label>`, etc.  Many users will use assistive technology such as a screen reader that gleans all its information from the markup rendered within the browsed page.

You are correct when you say that:

> I need to make it usable regardless of whether or not Javascript is enabled or not (It’s not my place to force those things on the user).

To do that, download a screen reader like [NVDA](https://www.nvaccess.org/) and actually pretend to have the accessibility needs of your target audience.  It's nice when your page passes validators, but it is much better when you actually know that the person you want to enable is actually enabled.